# How can i execute a function at an exact hour every day, in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a function that needs to be executed every day at an exact hour. How can i do that in asp.net? Do i need to use a webService or do i need to install something on the server or something else? How can this be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Scheduled Task to execute a C# console app.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of options, you could use:

- Windows Workflow Foundation that executes at a certain time (probably overkill for you)
- [SQL Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187061.aspx)  (probably best suited for SQL esc jobs)
- [Combine Web and Windows Services to Run Your ASP.NET Code at Scheduled Intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx)
- [Scheduled Tasks in ASP.NET Web Applications using Timers](http://weblogs.asp.net/samirgeorge/archive/2009/05/09/scheduled-task-in-asp-net-web-application-using-timers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ASPNET is a Request-driven model. It gets a request, for a document, a resource, a page... and then it runs some logic to generate that document, logic or page and transmit it to the requester.  It's not set up to "run" by itself.

So you have a couple options:
The way to get something to run at a particular time on Windows is via Task Scheduler. It's available on any recent Windows. You supply the EXE. In your case it might make sense to write a console EXE.
Use schtasks.exe (command line tool) or the control-panel applet to to set up the task, the login, the time and repeats.

The EXE could be an ASPNET client that makes a request to an ASPNET-managed resource.  Or it could just directly do the thing you want - maybe it's reading a database and creating a report.